# SVG image referrer policy

Tags: html, http, svg, referrer-policy

I have some HTML code which renders `<image/>`s inside an `<svg/>` and I would like to prevent the browser sending the referer header when it makes the request to get the image.
But it always does, and I can't find a way to stop it.

Example code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <svg>
            <g>
                <image href="https://some-third-party-image-provider.com" width="100px" height="100px" referrerPolicy="no-referrer"/>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

when it look in the network tab, the request to `https://some-third-party-image-provider.com` always has a `Referer: https://example.com` header.

Just for elimination, the following achieves what I want in respect of the Referer header:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="https://some-third-party-image-provider.com" referrerPolicy="no-referrer"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

but that isn't sufficient as I'm relying on the SVG for manipulation (specifically the graphics transform).

The following also makes it work:

```
<head>
    <meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer"/>
</head>
```

but I don't want to do that as other third party image providers need the referer header.

What I could do is funnel the requests through my own site which forwards them without the referer header. But that is suboptimal as it would increase the traffic of my own site.

(Oh, and yes, I've tried all possible combinations of the mis-spelling of 'referrer'...)

Comment: This is not part of the SVG 2 spec. Perhaps you should suggest to the w3c that they add support for via [their github issue tracker](https://github.com/w3c/svgwg/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen). Note that they have added referrerPolicy for link elements and Firefox (and possibly Edge) have implemented support there.

Comment: Hmm.. Can I ask why you are wanting to do this?  It sounds like you are trying  to get around the restrictions that sites use to limit people re-using their content., If that is the reason, then please reconsider it.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau, I have an account with the site that I am trying to get the data from, it's more to get round an apparent bug in their sites' recognition of the referrer, than to try and load content unauthorisedly. The referrer cannot be relied upon for AAA anyway, security is implemented by use of an API key, which I supply

Comment: @BenTaylor Ok. Just checking. Thanks for the explanation. :)